# NullPointerException in getOverlays() method

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I am seeing an issue in the code below where everytime I call the "getOverlays()" method of the MapView (appropriately called mapView) I receive a NullPointerException. This is a consistent event, even when I pass the result of the "getOverlays()" call into a variable then carry out the "add(itemisedOverlay) onto that. I have used the code of the Hello, MapView tutorial as a basis and reference for this code, with a little bit of modification to allow for the usage of the GPS location (gleaned from my experiences with the OSMdroid libraries used in an alternative prototype of this application). The objective here is to display the last known GPS location via the maps API with a small icon at that location.

In addition if I remove the try/catch declaration below this becomes a app breaking error.

Any help with eliminating the NullPointerException will be much appreciated!

TestMapDisplayGoogleActivity:

```
package com.test.google;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem;

import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class TestMapDisplayGoogleActivity extends MapActivity {

    Drawable drawable;
    TestItemizedOverlay itemisedOverlay;
    private GeoPoint center;

    LocationListener TestListener = new LocationListener() 
    {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            center = new GeoPoint((int) location.getLatitude(), (int)       location.getLongitude());;
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {
        // required for interface, not used
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {
        // required for interface, not used
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try
    {
        //Create the mapview & set basic settings
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);

        //Retrieve location manager and last know GPS location
        LocationManager locMan = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


        locMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2500, 100, TestListener);
        Criteria testCrit = new Criteria();
        testCrit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
        Location location = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        center = new GeoPoint((int) location.getLatitude(), (int) location.getLongitude());



        //Instantiate the overlays and create the item to be added to the overlay
        drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        itemisedOverlay = new TestItemizedOverlay(drawable);
        OverlayItem testItem = new OverlayItem(center, "Test", "Hey there!");

        //Add testItem to the overlay
        itemisedOverlay.addOverlayItem(testItem);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(itemisedOverlay);

        mapView.getController().setCenter(center);

        mapView.getController().setZoom(20);
        mapView.setSatellite(true);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.error_display);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }
}
```

Mapview in main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="[Location of API Key in real project]"
/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Error message:

```
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.google/com.test.google.TestMapDisplayGoogleActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at com.test.google.TestMapDisplayGoogleActivity.onCreate(TestMapDisplayGoogleActivity.java:74)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-02 03:53:00.294: E/AndroidRuntime(2589):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

This line should be the first one in the OnCreate() because it contains the mapview so untill and unless you set the view

`MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);` will return NULL

Comment: Odd that google would screw up their tutorial code like that, but this definitely is a step forward. Unfortunately by moving this to the the top of the try/catch statement (to move it fully to the top would eliminate the need for the statement) it also only displays the overlay on a blank screen, with no map data actually included.

Comment: It will actually prevent the result of Visible Force Close on the Screen. but the actual problem of WHY there is no data on MAP will remain as it is.